# Disabling EXM throws exception in logs about Dimension ID b459a0ca-9f43-4ac1-8e6d-549e2a3de674

Tags: exm

We are on Sitecore 9.0.2 upgraded scaled instance. Since we don’t have plans to use EXM module hence we disabled it. After disabling we are getting the following frequent exception in the logs:

```
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Dimension could not be resolved for for dimension id: b459a0ca-9f43-4ac1-8e6d-549e2a3de674
Source: Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.Data.Model.AggregationSegment.get_Dimension()
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.Data.Model.AggregationSegment.GetData(IVisitAggregationContext context)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.Pipeline.SegmentProcessor.ProcessSegments(IInteractionAggregationContext context, IEnumerable`1 segments)
```

Though nothing looks broken on the UI but the logs files are flooded with these exceptions. What are we missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raising a Sitecore support ticket, we came to know that it is knows bug on Sitecore 9.0.2 and provided a patch. Please download the patch from: https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.215205

If not a big fan of patching, stop both of your xConnect services and execute the SQL Script below on the ReferenceData Table. The first part will test that the ID’s are correct. You should get 10 results. The last part deletes the EXM definitions. Remember to set workflow state to “Workflows/Experience Analytics Segment/Inactive” on the items under “/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Experience Analytics/Dimensions/ExM/[ParentItem]” to avoid the definitions to come back in the database.

```
SELECT * FROM [xdb_refdata].[DefinitionMonikers]
  WHERE Moniker like '%a28b7ea2%' 
  or Moniker like '%0ec316ba%'
  or Moniker like '%0c385039%'
  or Moniker like '%0fc2e978%'
  or Moniker like '%605915a5%'
  or Moniker like '%c1745f34%'
  or Moniker like '%06b603c0%'
  or Moniker like '%1f031117%'
  or Moniker like '%7558fc89%'
  or Moniker like '%399d686d%'


DELETE FROM[xdb_refdata].[Definitions]
WHERE ID in (SELECT ID FROM [xdb_refdata].[DefinitionMonikers]
  WHERE Moniker like '%a28b7ea2%' or Moniker like '%0ec316ba%' or Moniker like '%0c385039%' or Moniker like '%0fc2e978%' or Moniker like '%605915a5%' or Moniker like '%c1745f34%' or Moniker like '%06b603c0%' or Moniker like '%1f031117%'
  or Moniker like '%7558fc89%' or Moniker like '%399d686d%')

DELETE FROM [xdb_refdata].[DefinitionMonikers]
WHERE ID  in (SELECT ID FROM [xdb_refdata].[DefinitionMonikers]
  WHERE Moniker like '%a28b7ea2%' or Moniker like '%0ec316ba%' or Moniker like '%0c385039%' or Moniker like '%0fc2e978%' or Moniker like '%605915a5%' or Moniker like '%c1745f34%' or Moniker like '%06b603c0%' or Moniker like '%1f031117%'
  or Moniker like '%7558fc89%' or Moniker like '%399d686d%')

DELETE FROM [xdb_refdata].[DefinitionCultures]
WHERE ID  in (SELECT ID FROM [xdb_refdata].[DefinitionMonikers]
  WHERE Moniker like '%a28b7ea2%' or Moniker like '%0ec316ba%' or Moniker like '%0c385039%' or Moniker like '%0fc2e978%' or Moniker like '%605915a5%' or Moniker like '%c1745f34%' or Moniker like '%06b603c0%' or Moniker like '%1f031117%'
  or Moniker like '%7558fc89%' or Moniker like '%399d686d%')
```

Visit this blog post for more details: https://solvingsitecore.wordpress.com/2018/09/24/segmentprocessor-failed-to-process-interaction-dimension-could-not-be-resolved/